# How to load and index C++ project to CLion without dependency

Tags: clion

I have big C++ project, with many dependences. I don't want to build it on my local PC, just edit, so i really don't want to install all dependences. But in this way, CLion doesn't index project, and i can't use: `Find Usages` and `Go To -> Declaration\Definition\...`. Is it possible to load and index C++ project in CLion without dependences?